# Insert 0 values into Postgres: Numeric Field Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, numeric

I have a problem when inserting "0" value into numeric field in PostgreSQL via PHP.

```
insert into canalis_db.cor_cust_corp_fncl_rprt 
(corp_fncl_rprt_id,
customer_id,
rprt_period,
asset) values(  
                        'ca423557-7788-36e3-7788-d36f8c130a83',
                        'ca4160e2-0189-12b7-e6a6-635819ac9aa2',
                        '2020', 
                        0)
```

it well show error message.

```
Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "0"
  Position: 395
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: 0
```

Is there something error in my sql syntax?

Comment: The above code should not be causing this error.  You may want to also include the relevant PHP code.

Comment: I already use squirel to run this code.. and the results is the same...

Comment: Are you certain that `asset` is a numeric column?

Comment: 4 asset numeric 22 4 1 cor_cust_corp_fncl_rprt   java.math.BigDecimal 24 asset 2 false false false false false true true true

Comment: I already check the DB, and the field is an existing field in the table.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] lin below it) and add the `create table` statement for `cor_cust_corp_fncl_rprt`. ([edit] your question, please do not post code as comments)

Comment: @LodeweykAndri . . . My guess is that you have some hidden characters in there that are causing a parsing problem.

Comment: Hi All, I already found the problem, somehow, the script for numeric cannot accept enter or space. so I just need to change the script into
insert into canalis_db.cor_cust_corp_fncl_rprt 
(corp_fncl_rprt_id,
customer_id,
rprt_period,
asset) values(  
                        'ca423557-7788-36e3-7788-d36f8c130a83',
                        'ca4160e2-0189-12b7-e6a6-635819ac9aa2',
                        '2020',0) . and it will run successfully